# Extending Application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

My site requires the user to be logged in via onRequestStart() in Application.cfc.
Then there is the registration folder, which has an Application.cfc that extends ApplicationProxy.cfc which extends the root Application.cfc.
This way the registration folder doesn't require the user to be logged in.

My problem is that the path on my dev server is different than the path on the production server.
So now my code is out of sync between dev and production because dev extends "clientname.components.ApplicationProxy" while production extends only "components.ApplicationProxy".

```
/Application.cfc
/components/ApplicationProxy.cfc extends Application
/Registration/Application.cfc extends ApplicationProxy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just be able to create a mapping in the CF admin. For example create a mapping called appextend, on dev it can point to clientname.components and on live just components. Then you can extend appextend.components.

Also check out this post: http://corfield.org/blog/index.cfm/do/blog.entry/entry/Extending_Your_Root_Applicationcfc

Comment: The link to Sean Corfield's post is no longer valid.

Answer (score 2):

It'd be best to use CF w/ Apache in a Multi-instance setup to mirror your dev folder structure just like your production folder structure.